# Return multiple match groups

Tags: python, regex

Trying to find a way to return 'A','B', and 'C'.

I've tried using the following regex:

```
{{(?:\|\[\[([a-zA-Z\s]+)+\]\])+}}
```

for the string:

```
{{|[[A]]|[[B]]|[[C]]}}
```

but so far little success.

Many thanks.

Comment: From what I can see it is returning the entire string, not just the letter. Do you want jus the letter back?

Comment: You need [`\|\[\[([a-zA-Z\s]+)\]\]`](https://regex101.com/r/IBfGo6/1) and get multiple matches. What is the programming language you are using it in? Note that `([a-zA-Z\s]+)+` is clearly a human error - there is no point in quantifying the group that has a single atom that is already `+` quantified.

Comment: What if the string was {{|[[A]]|[[B]]|[[C]]}}?

Comment: Yes, what if it is like this? The question is: what are you trying to achieve at all with the regex? And where? Are you trying to validate a string and extract part from it at the same time?

Comment: Yes, trying to extract the contents within the square brackets only when the string {{|[[A]]|[[B]]|[[C]]}} matches the regex.

Comment: Oh, I am using Python.

Comment: In this case add the Python tag to your post (systematically with regex questions).

Comment: Can you use a PyPi regex module? Or are you limited to `re`? BTW, is it Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Can, but would prefer not to? Using Python 2.7...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `([a-zA-Z\s]+)+` is clearly a human error - there is no point in quantifying the group that has a single atom that is already `+`-quantified.

If you can use PyPi regex module you could use your slightly fixed regex and just access Group 1 `captures`:

```
>>> import regex
>>> pat = r"{{(?:\|\[\[([a-zA-Z\s]+)]])+}}"
>>> s = "{{|[[A]]|[[B]]|[[C]]}}"
>>> res = regex.fullmatch(pat, s)
>>> print(res.captures(1))
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Else, you will have to use a 2-step approach: 1) check if the whole string matches the pattern you need, and 2) use `\|\[\[([a-zA-Z\s]+)]]` with `re.findall` to get multiple required matches.

```
>>> res = []
>>> if re.search(r"^{{(?:\|\[\[([a-zA-Z\s]+)]])+}}$", s):
    res = re.findall(r"\|\[\[([a-zA-Z\s]+)]]", s)
>>> print(res)
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex `\|\[\[[a-zA-Z\s]+\]\]` (without repetition) and look for multiple matches, where in each match you will find the first group to contain the letter: http://regexr.com/3eksj

Comment: New to this... Trying to extract the contents within the square brackets from a string, such as {{|[[A]]|[[B]]|[[C]]}}, whilst validating the that the string follows that pattern.

Comment: @bobblebubble fixed tnx, just took the original